# libinput is ignoring my conf file

Tags: xfce, libinput

I was trying to find a way to disable my touchpad while writing, so i installed libinput. The tap to click has been disabled, so i edited the file usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWg0z.jpg

to mantain its original behaviour.

But when i restart this is the result of xinput list-props "Elan Touchpad" :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPiHl.jpg

It basically ignore the other instructions apart from the "Accel Speed". This is confirmed in xorg.0.log.

What i'm trying to understand is if there is some kind of trickery behind this strange behaviour, because i'm kinda sure im making everything right. I even tried to make a custom script in /etc/init.d but it does not work. If i launch the commands xinput set-prop <...> manually they work ok for the session. All I want is to be able enable to tap to click and middle mouse click! Thank you in advance

update: i tried using false/true instead of 0/1 in the .conf file. it didnt worked

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text and paste it as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong options in the conf file.

For instance,

```
Option "Tapping Enabled" "1"
```

is wrong.

The correct one is

```
Option "Tapping" "True"
```

Regarding Accel Speed the correct syntax is

```
Option "AccelSpeed" "-0.525"
```

[The Ubuntu libinput manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man4/libinput.4.html)